# How to get the real directory where .net File.Create() puts the file? - Win11; VS2022 preView; netMaui App

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory, visual-studio-2022

I have this code that creates, check the existence, deletes, etc a file:

```
string _myFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyFile.txt");
Debug.Print(_myFilePath);// C:\Users\leode\AppData\Local\MyFile.txt
Debug.Print(File.Exists(_myFilePath).ToString());// False
File.Create(_myFilePath).Close();
Debug.Print(File.Exists(_myFilePath).ToString());// True
File.Delete(_myFilePath);
Debug.Print(File.Exists(_myFilePath).ToString());// False
```

When I run it, the file is not created in `LocalApplicationData` directory (in my case "`C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\`"), but in a different subdirectory that I found doing a search with the windows file explorer (in my case this subfolder was "`C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Packages\F0C6F5FC-4B4B-478D-958D-BAD69252637E_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalCache\Local`").

The program runs correctly, but How can I get this **real directory** where File.Create(), File.Exists() and File.Delete() are interacting with "MyFile.txt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, in a **Microsoft Learn** [course](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet-maui/store-local-data/2-compare-storage-options).

You can access the sandbox using the **AppDataDirectory** static property of the FileSystem class:

```
string path = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
```

Example. **FileSystem.AppDataDirectory** returns
"C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Packages\8BD0CA74-EE25-4D2F-8CF1-FCA28BBCD548_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalState"

This is the right place to store local data in a device.